# Why am I not able scrape Prometheus metrics from the pods using AWS ADOT Prometheus Collector

Tags: amazon-web-services, prometheus, amazon-adot, amazon-amp

Until now I was using Prometheus Helm chart and custom chart for scraping Pod metrics

I am trying to replace my current setup with AWS ADOT using Prometheus Collector.

My current setup is to export metrics from Collector -> AMP -> view metrics in AWS GRAFANA

```
#
# OpenTelemetry Collector configuration
# Metrics pipeline with Prometheus Receiver and Prometheus Remote Write Exporter sending metrics to Amazon Managed Prometheus
#
---
apiVersion: opentelemetry.io/v1alpha1
kind: OpenTelemetryCollector
metadata:
  name: my-collector-amp
spec:
  mode: deployment
  serviceAccount: adot-collector-sa
  podAnnotations:
    prometheus.io/scrape: 'true'
    prometheus.io/port: '8888'
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 250m
      memory: 1G
    requests:
      cpu: 250m
      memory: 1G
  config: |
    receivers:
      #
      # Scrape configuration for the Prometheus Receiver
      # This is the same configuration used when Prometheus is installed using the community Helm chart
      #
      prometheus:
        config:
          global:
            scrape_interval: 10s
            scrape_timeout: 10s

          scrape_configs:
          - job_name: kubernetes-apiservers
            bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: endpoints
            relabel_configs:
            - action: keep
              regex: default;kubernetes;https
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
              - __meta_kubernetes_endpoint_port_name
            scheme: https
            tls_config:
              ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
              insecure_skip_verify: true

          - job_name: kubernetes-nodes
            bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: node
            relabel_configs:
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
            - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
              target_label: __address__
            - regex: (.+)
              replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$$1/proxy/metrics
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
              target_label: __metrics_path__
            scheme: https
            tls_config:
              ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
              insecure_skip_verify: true

          - job_name: kubernetes-nodes-cadvisor
            bearer_token_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: node
            relabel_configs:
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_node_label_(.+)
            - replacement: kubernetes.default.svc:443
              target_label: __address__
            - regex: (.+)
              replacement: /api/v1/nodes/$$1/proxy/metrics/cadvisor
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_node_name
              target_label: __metrics_path__
            scheme: https
            tls_config:
              ca_file: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
              insecure_skip_verify: true

          - job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: endpoints
            relabel_configs:
            - action: keep
              regex: true
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape
            - action: replace
              regex: (https?)
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
              target_label: __scheme__
            - action: replace
              regex: (.+)
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
              target_label: __metrics_path__
            - action: replace
              regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
              replacement: $$1:$$2
              source_labels:
              - __address__
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
              target_label: __address__
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
              replacement: __param_$$1
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
              target_label: kubernetes_namespace
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
              target_label: kubernetes_name
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
              target_label: kubernetes_node

          - job_name: kubernetes-service-endpoints-slow
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: endpoints
            relabel_configs:
            - action: keep
              regex: true
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scrape_slow
            - action: replace
              regex: (https?)
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_scheme
              target_label: __scheme__
            - action: replace
              regex: (.+)
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_path
              target_label: __metrics_path__
            - action: replace
              regex: ([^:]+)(?::\d+)?;(\d+)
              replacement: $$1:$$2
              source_labels:
              - __address__
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_port
              target_label: __address__
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_param_(.+)
              replacement: __param_$$1
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
              target_label: kubernetes_namespace
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
              target_label: kubernetes_name
            - action: replace
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_pod_node_name
              target_label: kubernetes_node
            scrape_interval: 5m
            scrape_timeout: 30s

          - job_name: prometheus-pushgateway
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: service
            relabel_configs:
            - action: keep
              regex: pushgateway
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe

          - job_name: kubernetes-services
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
            - role: service
            metrics_path: /probe
            params:
              module:
              - http_2xx
            relabel_configs:
            - action: keep
              regex: true
              source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_annotation_prometheus_io_probe
            - source_labels:
              - __address__
              target_label: __param_target
            - replacement: blackbox
              target_label: __address__
            - source_labels:
              - __param_target
              target_label: instance
            - action: labelmap
              regex: __meta_kubernetes_service_label_(.+)
            - source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
              target_label: kubernetes_namespace
            - source_labels:
              - __meta_kubernetes_service_name
              target_label: kubernetes_name


          - job_name: xxxx-service-monitoring
            scrape_interval: 5m
            scrape_timeout: 30s
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
              - role: pod
            relabel_configs:
              - action: keep
                regex: xxxx;(9090|9121)
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number
              - action: replace
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
                target_label: container_name
              - action: replace
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
                target_label: pod_name

    processors:
      batch/metrics:
        timeout: 60s

    exporters:
      prometheusremotewrite:
        endpoint: https://aps-workspaces.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/workspaces/xxxxxx/api/v1/remote_write
        auth:
          authenticator: sigv4auth

    extensions:
      sigv4auth:
        service: "aps"
        region: us-east-1
        assume_role:
          arn: arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/xxxxx-role-amp-remote-write-adot

    service:
      extensions: [sigv4auth]
      pipelines:
        metrics:
          receivers: [prometheus]
          processors: [batch/metrics]
          exporters: [prometheusremotewrite]



---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: otel-prometheus-role
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes
      - nodes/proxy
      - services
      - endpoints
      - pods
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - apiGroups:
      - extensions
    resources:
      - ingresses
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
      - watch
  - nonResourceURLs:
      - /metrics
    verbs:
      - get

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: otel-prometheus-role-binding
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: otel-prometheus-role
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: adot-collector-sa
    namespace: default
```

I am adding custom job of scraping pod metrics which has port 9090 or 9121 and belongs to particular namespace.

```
 - job_name: xxxx-service-monitoring
            scrape_interval: 5m
            scrape_timeout: 30s
            kubernetes_sd_configs:
              - role: pod
            relabel_configs:
              - action: keep
                regex: xxxx;(9090|9121)
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_namespace
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_port_number
              - action: replace
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_container_name
                target_label: container_name
              - action: replace
                source_labels:
                - __meta_kubernetes_pod_name
                target_label: pod_name
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with my configuration and why I am not able to see metrics in Grafana. The dashboard I am using is Prometheus2.0 stats. Is it the dashboard problem or ADOT does not support Prometheus 2.0 stats